# Does a meta tag for "og:title" make redundant a meta tag for "title"?

Tags: html, facebook, seo, meta-tags

My site has these two meta tags which currently have the same value:

```
<meta name="title" content="My Title" />    
<meta property="og:title"  name="title" content="My Title" />
```

The second one is a format required for `facebook` connectivity.

Does this mean the first one is redundant and can be removed?

Answer (score 11):

It's best to have both tags present. The  tag tells Search engines about your page for indexing and also shows up as the title in SERPs. 
The og:title tag helps Facebook index content so your page can feature in-Facebook search results and also for defined content when that particular URL on your website is shared. Also helps to add the og:image attribute which is the preview image on standard Facebook posts/shares.

Also, there is no

```
<meta name="title".
```

It's

```
<title> ......... </title>
```

Answer (score 7):

No. The Facebook meta tag is not standard and you should not expect anyone else besides Facebook to use the value of that tag for anything.

Comment: This is incorrect (at least now anyway). There are many services which adhere to the Open Graph protocol, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397510/do-services-other-than-facebook-use-open-graph

Answer (score 3):

The first one is the standard title tag, which is usually same as the page title. It is (or atleast was) used by search engines. See [this](http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-title.html).

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to find no official reference which describes the first tag: `<meta name="title" content="My Title" />`. In practice, it seems to be of no use and if it ever was of use, I suspect it was just a lazy parser in a web crawler.

The second tag is of use. The [OpenGraph standard](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) is used for sharing by many sites other than Facebook. While it won't help search rankings directly, it may help indirectly by way of more attractive, better-formatted shares.

I'd suggest using more OpenGraph tags than just the `og:title`. Others, including `og:image` will help make better shares.

Answer (score 0):

Because your second meta tag also includes the name attribute any compliant parser should pick it up for the title. Therefore your first meta tag is redundant.

I don't know any system that uses the title meta tag though.