# List of Services for Open Graph Protocol

Tags: metadata, search-engine, facebook-opengraph

Reference that I found here:

[Do services other than Facebook use Open Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397510/are-open-graph-tags-just-for-facebook)

And of course searching a bit through the internet - mostly self written resources from blogs that contained no direct cited information / links. However, I didn't find any direct answers of a reasonably (decent) list available anywhere.

I also reviewed as a comparison for Schema.org's Microdata, but no list:

[OpenGraph or Schema.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402528/opengraph-or-schema-org)

So,
What are some services that also use OGP besides Facebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some web services that "consume" the Open Graph Protocol (OGP), besides Facebook:

- **Google Search** uses OGP (among other standards) to display rich snippets in search results. See their [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).
- **Google+** also takes [advantage](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) of OGP.
- **Twitter** uses OGP for [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/getting-started). "When the Twitter card processor looks for tags on your page, it first checks for the Twitter property, and if not present, falls back to the supported Open Graph property."
- **Bing** uses OGP for displaying rich search results. See their [webmaster help docs](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/marking-up-your-site-with-structured-data-3a93e731).
- **Embed.ly** uses OGP according to Yammer's [dev. docs](https://developer.yammer.com/opengraph/). This also means that every  service that uses Embed.ly will also benefit from OGP.
- **Mixi** (popular Japanese social site) seems to use OGP. Check their [dev. docs](http://developer.mixi.co.jp/en/connect/mixi_plugin/mixi_check/spec_mixi_check/).
- **Yandex** seems to index OGP for videos at least. Here is their [help docs](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=1116426) (in Russian).
- **Blekko** seems to use OGP according to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15194159/848845) by its CTO :)
- **Socialcast** (vmware) seems to support it according to this [blog post](http://montrics.blogspot.gr/2010/10/its-official-socialcast-reach-is-live.html).

Answer (score 0):

blekko uses Open Graph metatags for our izik tablet search app and ROCKZi news reading thingie to help select good images for links -- both show an image with every result link.

We've found that og:image has been quite common and reliable in production.