# Default website image for social sharing

Tags: html, facebook, social-media

Is there any way to set a default image that appears when I share my website on Facebook? I've noticed that Facebook usually fetches the first image from the site to use as a thumbnail.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to set the [open graph](https://ogp.me/) image meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/logo.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1024">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1024">
```

For more info check the **[docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)**

Comment: I used this way and it still picks a random image from my site?

Comment: I agree - still waiting for an answer to this. Just picks some random image on my site...

Comment: By random do you mean every other time it changes or is it the same picture but not the one you set in the meta tags?

Comment: For facebook this helped, however in linkedin if I try to add website as a link to my profile experiences it shows first img tag source image. :)

Comment: @MindaugasJačionis according to [linked-in](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) all you need is the `og:image` tag, maybe the image you are seeing at the moment is cached, the caching will last up to 7 days.

Comment: @MindaugasJačionis I've had similar problems with caching too, like Kitler said. Try clearing your browser cache and see what happens

Comment: @Rossco you'll need to [clear facebook's cache](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) of your website.

Answer (score 17):

Set an [`og:image`](http://ogp.me/#metadata) in the `<head>` of your HTML document like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
```

This is part of the Open Graph Protocol, respected by at least the following social media sites:

- Facebook (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#images)
- Twitter (see https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#opengraph)
- LinkedIn (see https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)
- Google+ (see https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)
- Pinterest (see https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/reference/)

(... and probably plenty more besides.)

In addition to setting the tag above, you *may* also want to:

- Clear the social media platform's cached version of your page's image (e.g. by using the platform's developer tools), so that you can see the change reflected immediately. For example, you can do this for Facebook, at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
- Add additional "structured properties" to specify things like the image's width or height, using the syntax described at http://ogp.me/#structured. This is described as a "best practice" by Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images.

Answer (score 14):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/lamb-full.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200">
```

Image size should be be at least 200px X 200px

Comment: Nice.    What is the default for all sites that share the link?  Is this just Facebook api?

Comment: @JoshYates1980 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397510/do-services-other-than-facebook-use-open-graph for more sites using open graph

Answer (score 11):

This my solution, it's work well:

```
<head>
    <!--FACEBOOK-->
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.website.com/logo.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1024">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="1024">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.website.com/"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Website title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Website description." />
<head>
```

You can make test with [Facebook Debug site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/).

Answer (score 9):

Facebook's servers will 'scrape' your website looking for an image to use when people share it. If you want to specify which image to use, put this in the the `<head></head>` section of your website:

- `<meta property="og:image" content="http://url-to-your-image.png">`

Facebook may have cached a copy of the previous random image. To get facebook to fetch again:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/logo.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/logo.jpg" />
```

The above is all you need to update for all social link previews. To check what a preview looks like on a platform you can test your link using the tools below:

- Twitter https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator
- Facebook/Instagram: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
- LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/