# When I share my website URL on LinkedIn its showing an image from my website. Can I change that image?

Tags: html, linkedin-api

When I share my website URL on LinkedIn, its showing an image from my website, but it's not a relevant image. Can I change the Preview Image?

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsite.com/" />
<meta property="og:type"  content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="yyyy" />
<meta property="og:description" content="yyyy" />
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/newtheme/img/logo.png" />
```

I already set these meta tags.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/81310/customizing-the-image-and-title-when-posting-a-url-on-your-company-page?lang=en)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632323/default-website-image-for-social-sharing

Comment: @jonathanbell not like this when i share my site url to some one else through personal message or when some one else share my website url its showing an image from my testimonial section. i need to change that

Comment: @juice since you set property="og:image" then I’d say perhaps the image is cached on the LinkedIn side of things. Or perhaps open graph wants a relative path?? Or one with the same domain as your site?

Answer (score 0):

As you already have set the `<og:image>` tag correctly, the only thing you have to check is whether the image to be displayed fulfills the requirements of LinkedIn.

According to the “[Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)” article, the image requirements specific to the LinkedIn sharing module are as follows:

- Max file size: 5 MB
- Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels

As the filename defined in your `<og:image>` tag is `logo.png`, I assume that it does not fulfill the size requirements described above.