# Sharing image on social media using HTML

Tags: php, html

I was trying to share an image on social media. I found a solution here:

[Default website image for social sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632323/default-website-image-for-social-sharing)

They say it works in this link but in my case when the window opens it diplays

> Warning href should represent a valid URL

I used  the same code. Here it is:

```html
<li class="social__item">
<div id="mImageBox">
<button id="my_image" alt=''  src='../../admin/views/images/<?php echo $result['image']; ?>' class="social__link" onclick="fbs_click(this)"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button>
</div>
<script>
function fbs_click(TheImg) {

    u=TheImg.src;

    t=TheImg.getAttribute('alt');

    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

    return false;

   }
 </script>
 </li>
```

I was expecting it will open the sharing window with the image and share button but the result was "href should represent a valid URL" with okay button.
How can I fix this or is there any other method of sharing an image on social media when clicking on a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `u=TheImg.src;` to `u=TheImg.getAttribute('src');`
Also note that to define variable as `var u`
If you sharing your pic to FB then write full url using `http://`

Comment: it works actually but not on localhost server :/ that means i cant use it right now untill i put my website on internet anyway thanks