# How to specify that "main" picture?

Tags: html, web

If I include an url in some applications, for example in a conversation thread in Facebook `Messenger` (www.messenger.com), the application is able to show a "key" image from that web site. Is there a special Html tag or attribute that allows the web author to specify which should be the image that is to be shown?

Example, pasting http://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/spencer-the-airport-robot-will-help-you-catch-your-flight/ in `Messenger` will display:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

> og:image -> The URL of the image that appears when someone shares the
>   content to Facebook. See below for more info, and check out our best
>   practices guide to learn how to specify a high quality preview image.

Comment: So it's not a common standard?  I see that Hangouts can show a screen grab for Youtube urls.

Comment: @OldGeezer The og meta tags is not specific to just Facebook, but not every social media site uses the Open Graph Protocol, if that is what you mean. http://ogp.me/

Comment: @OldGeezer Here is another question about the protocol and who uses it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397510/do-services-other-than-facebook-use-open-graph